# How do closures work in this particular case?

Tags: javascript

```
function createFunctionWithProperty(property) {
    functionWithProperty.property = property;
    return functionWithProperty;
    function functionWithProperty() {
    }
}

var a = createFunctionWithProperty(123);
var b = createFunctionWithProperty(321);
alert(a.property + " : " + b.property);  // 123 : 321
```

So as far as I know both `createFunctionWithProperty` and `functionWithProperty` are *function declarations* which are hoisted, parsed and brought into existence before any JavaScript code is executed. However at some moment, while calling the `createFunctionWithProperty` function, `functionWithProperty` becomes a closure, that is a very particular instance of the `functionWithProperty` function with it's own properties and variables it is closed over that are different per each instance. It's all in theory, but in this case I don't understand how things work. Would anyone give a detailed break down on when and how exactly `functionWithProperty` becomes a closure. Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is _not_ about closures.

Comment: @Mathletics, what is it about?

Answer (score 2):

In this case it doesn't matter if it's a function let alone a closure, you might as well have done:

```
function createObjectWithProperty(property) {
    var objectWithProperty = {};
    objectWithProperty.property = property;
    return objectWithProperty;
}

var a = createObjectWithProperty(123);
var b = createObjectWithProperty(321);
alert(a.property + " : " + b.property);
```

Comment: @War10ck you misread; the property is actually called `property` here.

Comment: but in your example I can clearly see where `objectWithProperty` is instantiated (the line with `var objectWithProperty = {}`)! in my case with a funciton it's not clear at all

Comment: @AlekseyBykov function declaration is hoisted, how is that not clear. If there was object declaration, it could be written like that too. But the point is that you are not using the function for its function nature at all and might as well use any kind of object in this code.

Comment: @AlekseyBykov hoisting occurs _in scope_. `functionWithProperty` is a local instance inside of `createFunctionWithProperty` and gets hoisted when `createFunctionWithProperty()` is called.

Comment: so are you guys saying that hoisting equals to having the very first imaginery line in the function body that kind of looks like: `var functionWithProperty = function() {}`?

Answer (score 2):

This example code that you've posted looks like it's exemplifying hoisting, and not closures. If you change:

```
function createFunctionWithProperty(property) {
    functionWithProperty.property = property;
    return functionWithProperty;
    function functionWithProperty() {
    }
}
```

to:

```
function createFunctionWithProperty(property) {
    functionWithProperty.property = property;
    return functionWithProperty;
    var functionWithProperty = function () {
    }
}
```

You will see that although `var functionWithProperty = function () {}` and `function functionWithProperty() {}` are both ways to declare a function, one will be hoisted, while the other will not be. Although both of these functions act as closures, this example doesn't really give a good example of why they act as closures, or the benefits or gotchas associated with closures in javascript.

Edit: I suppose that it also is a great example of how functions are first class objects in javascript (mostly). Differently from other languages, javascript allows you to assign properties to functions. Maybe that's what you are trying to understand by saying "closure."

Comment: MattDiamant, I perfectly know what you are talking about, and the question was exactly on how hoisted functions become closures.

Comment: Hoisted functions do not become closures. These are 2 completely seperate ideas in javascript programming. A closure is the idea that a function inside another function will have access to all the variables of the outer function. Hoisting is a weird thing in javascript where, regardless of where inside a function you define a variable, javascript will internally define it at the top of the function. This is why you are able to define `functionWithProperty.property`, even when the `function functionWithProperty() {}` would normally NEVER run, because it is after the return statement.

Comment: Updated my comment above to explain. Edit: Also, your comment above about the "imaginary line" is spot on correct :)

Comment: Comment to your edit: Somehow I thought that a *declared* function is a pure template, if you will, with placeholders for whatever out-of-scope variables used in it, and then when it is referred for the first time it creates an instance based on that template, checks its scope and fills the placeholders in that instance with whatever variables available immediately at that moment thus becoming a closure. The reality turned out to be much more boring :)